# Nginx limit_rate not applied to proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, debian

Is there any specific reason why limit_rate does not apply to proxy_pass? Having the following configuration block in nginx, I can still download the proxied file at ~4MB/s:

```
location ~ ^/proxy? {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    set $limit_rate  50k;
    limit_rate       50k;
    proxy_limit_rate 50k;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_buffer_size 15m;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_read_timeout 20s;
    proxy_pass  $arg_fwd;
}
```

System is Debian 8 with Nginx 1.10.1. No extra modules are installed aside from the default packaged ones in apt.

Answer (score 4):

`proxy_buffering off;` and rate limiting are mutually exclusive. You should enable buffering to use the limit rate feature.

Comment: Any doc about this?

Comment: okwap it's quite natural. Rate limiting is like having a dam on river. Having a dam always means having a reservoir where water is kept some time.

Comment: I'll second the "any doc about this" - the nginx docs say nothing at all about these directives being mutually exclusive and I see no reason why they need to be that way. (In response to VBart's point: you don't have to have a reservoir to rate-limit; you can just stop receiving bytes from the proxy.)